# angular 6 how to display a number without comma

Tags: angular6

I am using Angular 6 and want to format a simple number value. This is not an amount value and it is a simple count value.

I want to have number like 8,245 and would like to display it without the comma: 8245.

When I use

```
{{ 8245 | number }}
```

it comes up with comma.

How I can do it without comma?

Comment: Why not display as is, without any pipe? Are there any other constraints for the display?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use pipe if you don't want to display comma in number. Simply use

```
{{8245}}
```

and if you have stored that number in variable i.e. number = 8245 then use `{{number}}`